# Elasticsearch inverted search query

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to use elasticsearch to search among data that must be included in my search query.

Example:

```
{
  "query":{
     "match":{       
       "field":"some data to be searched"
      }
   }
}
```

the following field should be returned because the query data contains both `some` and `data`

```
{
 "field":"some data"
}
```

but this search query shouldn't return anything:

```
{
  "query":{
     "match":{ 
        "field":"data to be searched"
      }
   }
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) to achieve your use case.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field": {
        "query": "some data",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "field": "data to be searched"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": []
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "field": "some data to be searched"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67658971",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.26152915,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "field": {
                "query": "some data",
                "operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```